# creating a functional array to store names of files in a folder

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

i want to create a functional array that stores all name of file in perticular folder

this is what i tried..

```
Function number_of_file(i As Integer) As Variant

Dim file_object As Object
Dim files_in_folder() As Variant

Set file_object = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").getfolder("D:\ls")

i = 0
For Each obj In file_object.Files
ReDim files_in_folder(i)
    files_in_folder(i) = obj.Name
    i = i + 1
Next obj

number_of_files = files_in_folder
End Function


sub test()
files_in_folder(2)
end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the array of file names and also store that array in column **A**:

```
Sub MAIN()
   Dim FolderOfInterest As String, i As Long
   FolderOfInterest = "C:\TestFolder"
   Dim ary()
   ary = files_in_folder(FolderOfInterest)
   MsgBox "There are " & UBound(ary) & " files in folder " & FolderOfInterest
   '
   '  Now store the array in a worksheet column
   '
   i = 1
   For Each a In ary
      Cells(i, "A").Value = a
      i = i + 1
   Next a
End Sub

Public Function files_in_folder(folderS As String) As Variant
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderS)
   ReDim temp(1 To folder.Files.Count)

   i = 1
   For Each file In folder.Files
      temp(i) = file.Name
      i = i + 1
   Next file

   files_in_folder = temp
End Function
```

***NOTE:***

The function returns an array of strings, *(one based)*.  The number of files is then upper bound of that array.